# Highlight current category, when using get_categories

Tags: menus, categories

I'm successfully using helgatheviking's answer from this post: [Show children of top level category only](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65095/show-children-of-top-level-category-only) See code below:

```
// get the category object for the current category
$thisCat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); 

// if not top-level, track it up the chain to find its ancestor
while ( intval($thisCat->parent) > 0 ) {
    $thisCat = get_category ( $thisCat->parent );
}

//by now $thisCat will be the top-level category, proceed as before
$args=array(
    'child_of' => $thisCat->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories=get_categories( $args );
foreach( $categories as $category ) { 
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="'     . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' .     $category->name.'</a>';  } 
?>
```

However, in this list of sub categories, I need to highlight the current category. I'm sure there is an easy answer, but I can't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved my problem. I added this definition before my old code:

```
<?php
// get the category object for the current category
$thisTrueCat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); 
print $thisTrueCat->term_id;
?>
```

The above `$thisTrueCat`, different from `$thisCat` in the already existing code, retrieves the ID of the current category regardless of it's parent. `$thisCat` on the other hand is set up to default back to the ID of the current category's parent.

With `$thisTrueCat` established, I then added the below code inside the loop:

```
<li <?php if ($thisTrueCat->term_id == $category->term_id) { ?> class="xshown" <?php } ?>
```

This will give the list item the class xshown if the current category displayed match the category of the list item. In other words, with CSS, I highlight the category currently displayed.

Here's my new code in it's entirety:

```
    <!-- call ID of thisTrueCat -->
<?php
// get the category object for the current category
$thisTrueCat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); 
print $thisTrueCat->term_id; ?>

<ul class="submenu">
<!-- call submenu -->
<?php
    // get the category object for the current category
    $thisCat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); 

    // if not top-level, track it up the chain to find its ancestor
    while ( intval($thisCat->parent) > 0 ) {
        $thisCat = get_category ( $thisCat->parent );
    }

    //by now $thisCat will be the top-level category, proceed as before
    $args=array(
        'child_of' => $thisCat->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $categories=get_categories( $args );
    foreach( $categories as $category ) { ?>
        <li <?php if ($thisTrueCat->term_id == $category->term_id) { ?> class="xshown" <?php } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ?>" ><?php echo $category->name ?></a></li>  
    <?php
    }; 
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good you figured it out and thanks (+1) for sharing your solution! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Particularly since you're putting the categories into an unordered list, it seems worth mentioning that [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) gives a class to the current category by default on archive pages, comes with a `$current_category` argument for special use cases, and is really just a complicated wrapper function of `get_categories()`.

I don't know the exact context of your code, but it's quite possible you can replace it with the following:

```
<?php
// get the category object for the current category
$thisCat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); 

// if not top-level, track it up the chain to find its ancestor
while ( intval($thisCat->parent) > 0 ) {
    $thisCat = get_category( $thisCat->parent );
}
$args = array(
    'child_of' => $thisCat->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0
); ?>
<ul class="submenu">
    <?php echo wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

That would give you the CSS class `current-cat` on the `<li>` and also `current-cat-parent` should that ever apply (though in your case I don't think it would ever come up).

---

As an accessibility aside [the title attribute is mostly useless](http://blog.silktide.com/2013/01/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/) so it's good just to turn that off (as in the code above) and not include it in theme code. [WordPress core is slowly moving toward doing that itself.](http://make.wordpress.org/accessibility/2013/12/12/remove-title-attributes-trac-tickets/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this as well.

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'order'   => 'ASC'
            ) );
    foreach( $categories as $key=>$category ) :
     $catLink = get_category_link( $category->term_id ); 
     $classactive = ( is_category( $category->name ) ) ? 'active' : '';
    ?>
    <li class="<?=$classactive?>">
        <a href="<?=$catLink?>"><?= $category->name  ?> 
            <span><?= $category->count ?></span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.